# How do I make the titlepage's title smaller in tufte-book?

Tags: fontsize, tufte

For now, I have what is probably a much too long book title. I'm not certain I will come up with something both better and shorter. TeX tries desperately to fit it in, and manages to do so in five lines and one hyphenation.

My MWE is pretty simple:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, nobib]{tufte-book}

\title{\bf Somebigword for abigtopic, abigbigtopic, and andyetanotherbigbigword lastword}

\maketitle
```

I would like to remove all hyphenation first, but also get it down to no more than three lines of title (two seems unrealistically optimistic). I figured that I could play with font sizes until I got it right myself. I would very much like to not affect anything else, as it's getting pretty close to borderline-not-awful-looking.

In other answers, people have suggested redefining the maketitle macro, but it's complicated enough that I can't figure out what I'd change. Presumably the LARGE keyword...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, redefining the maketitlepage macro is the way to go if you do not want to affect other parts of the document.

Change the title font and size this way:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
  \begingroup%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

  {\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont{\@author}\par}

  \vspace{2cm}
  {\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont\textbf\@title\par}

  \vspace{1.5cm}
  {\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\textsf{\@date}\par}

  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Then use `mbox` to prevent hyphenation.

Just play around with the font size and line breaks yourself until it looks the way you want.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, nobib]{tufte-book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
  \begingroup%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

  {\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont{\@author}\par}

  \vspace{2cm}
  {\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont\textbf\@title\par}

  \vspace{1.5cm}
  {\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\textsf{\@date}\par}

  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\author{Author}
\title[Short Title]{%
  \mbox{Somebigword for abigtopic}, \mbox{abigbigtopic}, and \\
  \mbox{andyetanotherbigbigword} \\ 
  lastword
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]